# Catching drag cancel event in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, drag-and-drop

I'm experiencing some difficulties with catching application-scope events in Qt.

My purpose is to catch every user action in some GUI application. Of course I've overrided `QApplication::notify` handler and processing different types of application-scope events there. Something like that:

```
bool CoolApplication::notify(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        // Handle mouse
        break;

    case QEvent::Wheel:
        // Handle wheel
        break;

    case QEvent::KeyPress:
    case QEvent::KeyRelease:
        // Handle keyboard and so on
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return QApplication::notify(obj, e);
}
```

That works pretty well until user starts drag-and-drop operation. Mouse press event is handled well, it is catched in my handler, life is beautiful there. The problems start when I try to catch mouse release event on Windows.

When entering drag operation mouse and keyboard events are no longer handled by QApplication::notify. It is possible to catch drop event when it was successfull (I can add `case QEvent::Drop` branch into my handler), but how to catch ignored drop or canceling drop with Esc? It seems impossible to be done directly, maybe I can catch drag event loop termination event or something like that? Or even maybe someone knows a direct way to do it?

Edit:
Once more turning the attention that I need to catch application-scope event, not the widget one

Comment: There is DragEnter event, this event means that user starts dragging and Enter the widget. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @Chernobyl, thanks, I know about drag events existance, but they won't help. I need drag termination event, neither enter nor leave.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this

```
bool QtCoreApplication::notify(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
    {
        switch (e->type()) {
        case QEvent::QDropEvent:
            QDropEvent* dropEvent = (QDropEvent*)e;
            dropEvent->keyboardModifiers(); // keys pressed
            dropEvent->dropAction(); // Drop result
        break;

        return QApplication::notify(obj, e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for yor answer, @Krionix, but it is not the thing I need. Your proposal works for concrete widget, but I need to process  application-scope events. That means that drag can be ignored by different widgets and even windows and I steel need to know the moment it was interrupted

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean, sorry for offtop answer.
This is because the drag operation is a blocking operation exec() and the main event loop is waiting for the drag to finish, that is why all other events are not handled. You nedd to add "case QEvent::Drop" in your notify function and ask
your QDropEvent for any modifier keys QDropEvent::keyboardModifiers() and drop result. Thanks.

Comment: I know that too, I even wrote that at the bottom of the question. But `QEvent::Drop` is not notified when user drags into a widget that did not accept it, in other words if drag had cursor of striked out circle. That event is just not fired, you can try yourself :) But thanks for your proposals

Comment: @dvvrd, you are right on this issue, and it's a Windows specific problem 'cause QDrag::exec has platform dependendent implementation. 
From Qt source code: On Linux and Mac OS X, the drag and drop operation can take some time, but this function does not block the event loop. Other events are still delivered to the application while the operation is performed. On Windows, the Qt event loop is blocked while during the operation.

Comment: There is no common and simple approach to process application events during drag and drop operation on Windows. The one way is to place QDrag in separate thread, which has own event loop. But in such case you need to reimplement all used drag and drop widgets :(

Comment: I saw how windows drag-n-drop implemented in Qt. They just register their callbacks somewhere in WinAPI methods and handle them in a complex way... One of the ways of solving my problem is using WinAPI too, the second one - to reuse somehow QWindowsDrag code. Here I`m just looking for a pretty way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As this remained an open item to us, we checked the usage of the [`destroyed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#destroyed) signal.
This is fired at the moment the element is discarded, which seems to happen a the moment the QDrag is killed by the Escape key pressure

```
void dragDestroyed()
{
    qDebug("drag and drop cancled by Escape key");
}


QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
connect( drag, SIGNAL(destroyed()), this, SLOT(dragDestroyed()) );
drag->exec(Qt::MoveAction);
```

probably this is relevant for anyone facing the issue.