# How to track the lifetime of a Drag/Drop operation?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt5

I have an application which let's me drag&drop items from a modified `QListWidget` on to a modified `QLabel` using `startDrag()`, `dragEnterEvent()`, `dropEvent()`, etc.

I now want to not only get notified, when the dragging **starts** but also when it get's **interrupted** (by pressing `ESC` or dropping somewhere in the void). (My goal is to uncover a hidden widget I can drop items on which hides again as soon as the drag operation gets interrupted.)

I crawled the docs but find anything promising - has someone accomplished this already?

There is a quite [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443890/catching-drag-cancel-event-in-qt) already but it didn't get useful answers and it's two years old - so maybe there are some new trickies introduced by Qt5?

Comment: This question has a totally different intention: I want to know how I can get informed about a drag&drop operation has ended - either by dropping on a valid target or by being aborted (dropped in an invalid area or by pressing `ESC`) The other question asks how I avoid a memory leak caused by creating new instances of `QMimeData` every time the source widgets `mimeData()` method gets called.

Comment: Misunderstood this one.

Comment: Can you un-duplicate this question or do I have to edit the title?

Comment: It's no longer flagged as a dupe that I can see. Btw, I would introduce your comment back into the question to prevent any more confusion, i.e., clarify the question a bit.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt 4 up until at least Qt 5.7, drag is pseudo-synchronous. It starts the moment `QListWidget::startDrag` is entered and calls `QDrag::exec()`, and ends when `QListWidget::startDrag` returns. Thus, you might have:

```
void startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions) override {
   emit dragStarted();
   QListWidget::startDrag(supportedActions); // reenters the event loop
   emit dragStopped();
}
```

Easy-peasy, if it ignores whether a drag actually took place (it could be filtered out).

But this implementation might change, and indeed it should change: event loop reentering is a mess. And we'd also like to know if `QDrag::exec()` was really called on a `QDrag` instance. Thus we need to check the existence of a `QDrag` instance after the control returns to the event loop (either by returning or by re-entering).

We can leverage `QDrag` being a child of the `QAbstractItemView`. Once the drag has started, you can find the instance and track its lifetime. The lifetime monitoring requires posting a functor to the event loop to cope with the pseudosynchronous drag implementation at the moment. The code below will still work if/when drag becomes fully asynchronous.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/drag-lifetime-37846521
#include <QtWidgets>

template <typename F>
static void postToThread(F && fun, QObject * obj = qApp) {
   QObject src;
   QObject::connect(&src, &QObject::destroyed, obj, std::forward<F>(fun),
                    Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

struct MyListWidget : QListWidget {
   Q_SIGNAL void dragStarted();
   Q_SIGNAL void dragStopped();
   MyListWidget() {
      setDragEnabled(true);
      addItem("item1");
      addItem("item2");
   }
   void startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions) override {
      postToThread([this]{
         auto drag = findChild<QDrag*>();
         if (drag) {
            emit dragStarted();
            connect(drag, &QObject::destroyed, this, &MyListWidget::dragStopped);
         }
      }, this);
      QListWidget::startDrag(supportedActions); // reenters the event loop
   }
   Q_OBJECT
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QWidget gui;
   QVBoxLayout layout(&gui);
   MyListWidget list;
   QLabel label;
   layout.addWidget(&list);
   layout.addWidget(&label);
   QObject::connect(&list, &MyListWidget::dragStarted, [&]{ label.setText("Drag Active"); });
   QObject::connect(&list, &MyListWidget::dragStopped, [&]{ label.clear(); });
   gui.show();
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/q/37846843/1668622 this answer does not work for me. The label text gets set but not cleared..

Comment: @frans On the contrary, the answer works because it indicates exactly what's happening - a Qt bug. If the first code snippet (the simpler `startDrag`) also doesn't signal the end of drag then it indicates a very serious bug where not only `QDrag` leaks but the event loop is re-entered multiple times. This will cause multiple other memory leaks since `deleteLater` is deferred until the control returns to outermost event loop. Don't fight with Qt bugs: fix them or report them. You're not doing anything wrong, it's supposed to work and there's no need for workarounds.

Comment: @frans IOW, this definitely tracks the lifetime of a `QDrag`, and highlights a bug where `QDrag` is kept around even after the drag has ended. I've checked on Windows and there it works properly too. You have found a X11-related Qt bug, it looks like. Report it. You have a test case already.

Comment: Fight a Qt bug? Like this one?: http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2010/06/01/article-1282890-09D495A6000005DC-862_634x303.jpg I can't! I'll rather try to reproduce and report it...